# Export a Gameobject to USDZ in Unity for Android and iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, usdz

I have tried using the usd sdk from Unity and it seems like there is no support for usdz export in runtime for iOS and Android in Unity. I was wondering

1. If anyone is familiar with any other external Plugins to Achieve this?
2. If there is no directly available solution, how can I approach this? Can you give me some direction?

So far I tried the usd sdk from unity, looked into a few blog posts on how to do it natively in iOS , and found a way to do it on webXR using Needle Engine SDK in Unity. But no lead so far with iOS , and Android